# Why do we need stack cleanup code and how does it work?(In assembly language)

Tags: assembly, stack

Stack is a data structure that follows the LIFO rule. In assembly language, when we are calling a function we need to push the arguments onto the stack using "push" instruction. But why do we need stack cleanup code to remove the arguments? Most stack cleanup code looks like

```
add esp N
```

How does that remove the arguments from the stack?

Comment: The stack pointer register (ESP) points to the top of the stack. Since the stack grows down, increasing the value of ESP removes items from the stack. Changing the value of ESP is the only way to remove items from the stack, whether explicitly with an ADD or LEA instruction or implicitly with POP or RET.

Comment: There are calling conventions where the called function restores esp, typically by using | ret N | to return from the called function. There are also calling conventions where the caller would normally restore esp, but where space is pre-allocated for a fixed number of parameters, and as long as the actual number of parameters in a call is <= the pre-allocated number, the parameters are just stored as offsets from esp, and esp does not need to be restored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll first answer the first part of OP's question: why? Because for most CPU's, the stack carries both local storage for the current function (local variables and arguments) and control information (return address, pointer to previous stack frame, etc)

When you call a function that does not clean itself the stack (for example, functions that adhere to the cdecl calling convention), the caller is responsible for leaving the stack after the callee returns, in the same state as it was before the call. That means that if the caller pushes N bytes to the stack, it has to remove N bytes from the stack, either by popping and throwing them away, or faster, by skipping those bytes by directly modifying the value of the stack pointer (that is, the ADD SP,N instruction). Otherwise, the stack would grow for every called function that is not cleaned, and eventually, a stack overflow would happen.

Comment: I just found that when I'm doing code injection, if i don't clean up the stack after I call a function with arguments, the injected program will crash. How does that happen? I just pushed an integer onto the stack, did that 4 bytes crash the program?

Comment: Because if you don't leave the stack at the same state it was before the calling, your RET instruction will fetch the return address from an incorrect place

Answer (score 1):

For a stack that grows down, meaning it starts with a higher address and when you execute a push instruction it subtracts some value off of the stack pointer.   The function needs to return the stack (pointer) as it found it.  So you can do a bunch of pop instructions which in this case add to the stack pointer address, or you can simply add to the stack pointer the amount pushed.  Or another solution is you can save the stack pointer in a way that doesnt interfere with the caller and simply restore that value.  A bunch of pop instructions is generally a waste of instruction space and execution time, esp when one add instruction can effectively do the same thing.

cleaning the stack in no way means actually restoring the ram you messed with on the stack, by definition that ram, below the stack pointer, is fair game, it just means returning the stack pointer to its as called state.

Answer (score 0):

> The stack pointer register (ESP) points to the top of the stack. Since the stack grows down, increasing the value of ESP removes items from the stack. Changing the value of ESP is the only way to remove items from the stack, whether explicitly with an ADD or LEA instruction or implicitly with POP or RET

- [Ross Ridge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3826372/ross-ridge)

Comment: How do callee functions access the arguments without pop?

Comment: If changing the value of ESP is the only way to remove items, what is pop instruction for?

Comment: @KelvinZhang I didn't write this answer. But, if you want something to look into, look up "stack frame"

Comment: @KelvinZhang POP removes items from the stack by changing the value of ESP.

Comment: @Ross Ridge how does the callee function read the arguments without changing the stack?

Comment: @KelvinZhang By either using ESP or the saved stack pointer value in EBP as the base of an indirect memory operand. For example: `mov eax,[esp + 8]` or `add eax, [ebp - 4]`.